# formatting y-axis in ggplot with circular data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set of angular data (0-360) corresponding to a time signature (0-100) and am using ggplot to create a scatter plot.

```
ggplot(kfaf)+
geom_point(aes(time, angle, color = condition), size = 1.5)
```

[image: Example Graph]

What i'm trying to do is format the y-axis so that 0=360 and it reads from ymin = 270 to ymax = 269, functionally shifting the graph so 0/360 is in the middle of the y-axis. Can't find anything for formatting axis for circular data, help?

Comment: It would be best if you provided a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It is hard to understand exactly what you want? do you mean for the plot to go from -180 to 180? if so `ggplot(kfaf)+
geom_point(aes(time, y=ifelse(angle>180,angle-360,angle), color = condition), size = 1.5)` should work

Comment: Hi user2738526, thanks for commenting. Yes, this would produce the graph i am after, however, then the y-axis would read -180 to 180. Is there a way to overcome that so it reads as circular data where below 0 should be descending values from 360?

Comment: I guess you could fudge it with `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-180,180,by = 90), labels = c(180,270,0,90,180))` if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

#### 1st attempt (but not fully meeting OP's expectations)

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to plot the data so that the y-axis covers a range from -270 to +270 degrees.

This can be achieved by doubling the data and shifting the `angle` values:

```
# create dummy data
DF <- data.frame(angle = seq(0, 350, 10),
                 time = 1:36)

# doubling the data
library(dplyr)
DF2 <- DF %>% 
  mutate(angle = angle - 360) %>% 
  bind_rows(DF)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF2) +
  aes(time, angle) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-360, 360, 60), limits = c(-270, 269)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### 2nd attempt

The OP has clarified that he does not want negative values on the y-axis. This can be accomplished by setting the labels in addition to the breaks in the call to `scale_y_continuous()`:

```
brks <- seq(-360, 360, 30)
lbls <- brks %% 360 %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  replace(. == "0", "0/360")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF2) +
  aes(time, angle) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks, labels = lbls, limits = c(-90, 269)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The limits have been set to range from -90 to 269 degrees which are printed as 270 to 269 as requested.

Deliberately, I have choosen to modify the label for 0 degrees to `"0/360"` in order to indicate the circular character (and in line with the plot in polar coordinates below).

#### Different approach: Polar cooordinates

Another possibility is to plot the original dataset `DF` in polar coordinates:

```
ggplot(DF) +
  aes(angle, time) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 360, 60), limits = c(0, 360)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that the arguments in `aes()` have swapped. The x-axis represents angle.

Comment: Hi Uwe, thanks for posting. this is not quite what i'm after (but great option with the polar coordinates). I'm wanting to format the y-axis so it works with circular data which is nonlinear. This would mean that below 0 on the y-axis should be values descending from 360. Any more options? Thanks.